# Group data by minimizing variance in R

Tags: r, database, algorithm, function

First, I would like to convey my appreciation to the community at large - I have learned a great deal simply by perusing through the forums.

I have a question pertaining to the grouping of variables and could appreciate the help.

I have a data set with multiple columns ('1' through '5'). I would like to group the data in such a way that the average of column '1' (Banding) is closest to 100%. For example, the hypothetical data looks like this:

```
Banding Gender  Country Type    BirthYear   Salary
220.9%  Male    Canada  alpha   1962    7,779.15
112.2%  Male    Canada  alpha   1946    1,355.64
80.8%   Male    Canada  alpha   1959    24,535.52
83.7%   Male    Canada  alpha   1943    3,961.32
112.6%  Male    Canada  alpha   1965    17,388.12
146.2%  Male    Canada  beta    1943    2,915.33
54.8%   Male    Canada  beta    1949    5,005.50
138.6%  Male    Canada  beta    1949    17,297.12
141.5%  Male    Canada  beta    1942    494.52
137.0%  Male    Canada  beta    1943    2,054.52
54.0%   Male    UStates alpha   1940    208.56
62.1%   Male    UStates alpha   1946    1,216.68
19.5%   Male    UStates alpha   1960    5,589.45
134.6%  Male    UStates alpha   1959    5,928.50
39.6%   Male    UStates alpha   1952    4,486.02
149.5%  Male    UStates beta    1954    3,427.36
95.6%   Male    UStates beta    1940    313.10
113.7%  Male    UStates beta    1942    927.00
120.4%  Male    UStates beta    1954    3,408.36
170.7%  Male    UStates beta    1937    606.60
88.1%   Male    Canada  alpha   1941    727.67
201.1%  Male    Canada  alpha   1946    1,715.88
347.3%  Male    Canada  alpha   1969    1,438.92
380.3%  Male    Canada  alpha   1941    282.60
506.2%  Male    Canada  alpha   1942    1,167.48
418.7%  Female  Canada  beta    1943    934.40
109.0%  Female  Canada  beta    1952    4,831.43
223.7%  Female  Canada  beta    1953    2,161.06
193.8%  Female  Canada  beta    1954    5,119.91
83.9%   Female  Canada  beta    1963    14,716.20
76.3%   Female  UStates alpha   1960    6,255.56
241.6%  Female  UStates alpha   1944    1,567.68
79.9%   Female  UStates alpha   1942    622.77
42.8%   Female  UStates alpha   1952    2,149.20
78.0%   Female  UStates alpha   1951    2,689.20
65.7%   Female  UStates beta    1951    11,721.19
179.7%  Female  UStates beta    1923    1,362.00
136.0%  Female  UStates beta    1945    528.48
74.1%   Female  UStates beta    1966    25,290.89
127.1%  Female  UStates beta    1963    7,451.59
19.2%   Female  Canada  alpha   1942    2,070.19
116.2%  Female  Canada  alpha   1936    298.66
118.6%  Female  Canada  alpha   1958    428.28
108.1%  Female  Canada  alpha   1954    3,610.08
99.1%   Female  Canada  alpha   1943    519.48
135.9%  Female  UStates beta    1940    63.96
144.2%  Female  UStates beta    1968    23,851.96
119.3%  Female  UStates beta    1936    1,376.76
112.9%  Female  UStates beta    1951    2,527.56
129.0%  Female  UStates beta    1949    1,061.88
```

I would like to get an output that looks like the second table. From the second table, the program has determined that BirthYear is not an important variable and has simultaneously banded salary to get the bins that get 'banding' to close to 100 as possible. It's not important to use all the variables, but it would be nice to have a minimum amount of samples in each grouping.

Right now, I'm using a series of Pivot Tables in Excel and CART analysis in R to get the banding to as close to 100. It's a lot of trial / error and takes a many hours (the real dataset contains many variables and over 50,000 rows).

```
Gender  Country             Type    Salary      Banding 
Male    Canada and Ustates  Alpha   <1000           112.5           
Male    Canada and Ustates  Alpha   1000-4000       117             
Male    Canada and Ustates  Alpha   >4000           108         
Male    Canada and Ustates  Beta    <1000           110         
Male    Canada and Ustates  Beta    1000-4000       98              
Male    Canada and Ustates  Beta    >4000           97          
Female  Canada              Alpha   <1000           100
Female  Canada              Alpha   1000-4000       115 
Female  Canada              Alpha   >4000           117.5
Female  Canada              Beta    <1000           118
Female  Canada              Beta    1000-4000       110 
Female  Canada              Beta    >4000           115
Female  Ustates             Alpha   <1000           102
Female  Ustates             Alpha   1000-4000       99  
Female  Ustates             Alpha   >4000           101
Female  Ustates             Beta    <1000           116
Female  Ustates             Beta    1000-4000       102 
Female  Ustates             Beta    >4000           98
```

Thank you all. Any help is appreciated friends.

Happy Coding.

Comment: The groups (Gender x Country x Type) are fixed? All groups will end up with the same Salary bins? Would you rather 2 bins at 110 and 115 or 3 bins at 101,111,116? How do you do the trade off between closeness to 100 and  number of bins?

Comment: @MaxFt. Thanks for the clarifying questions. The groups are indeed all fixed. It's not necessary for the Salary bins to be the same (although, most of the time they are). In the past, when I do this kind of analysis with Pivot tables / CART, I normally like to have a minimum number of samples in each final bin (~1000).  If I get into a situation where the increase in the number of bins decreases the sample in the bins to less than 1000, I combine the bins together. 

Thank you friend.

Comment: A minimum of 1000 observations per bins got it. Let's say you have a group composed of 6000 people. Would you rather 2 salary bins of 3000 people with banding averages of 90 and 110 or 3 bins of 2000 persons with averages of 98,105,115? for example. My question is: Do either of intra or inter group variance matter? Or all that matters is your average distance from 100 over all groups

Comment: @MaxFt. Thanks again. I understand your question. The primary objective is to keep the average distance from 100 over all groups. I've had a few situations similar to the one that you posted: 1) 2 bins of 3000; 2) 3 bins of 2000.  In these situations, if the average Banding hasn't gotten closer to 100 with the addition of another bin, I've erred on the side of having fewer bins. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about what exactly you are trying to optimize, and then define it in a mathematical way.  What are your constraints, how much weight do you put on each objective, etc?  That will help you find the most optimal grouping more than anything else.

Here is one approach using random search:

```
library(dplyr)
dat$Banding <- gsub("\\%", "", dat$Banding) %>% as.numeric
band_vals <- matrix(dat$Banding, ncol=1)
max_groups <- 20
min_groups <- 10
min_group_size <- 2

iters <- 100000
cost_vector <- rep(NA, iters)
best_cost <- Inf
n_groups <- sample(min_groups:max_groups, size=iters, replace=T)
for(iter in 1:iters) {
  set.seed(iter)
  x <- sample(n_groups[i], size=nrow(dat), replace=T)
  if(any(table(x) < min_group_size)) next;
  x_mat <- matrix(nrow = n_groups[i], ncol = nrow(dat), 0)
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    x_mat[x[i], i] <- 1/sum(x==x[i])
  }
  cost <- sum(( (x_mat %*% band_vals) - 100 )^2)
  if(cost < best_cost) {
    best_cost <- cost
    best_x <- x
  }
  cost_vector[iter] <- best_cost
}

dat$group <- best_x
plot(na.omit(cost_vector), type="l")
dat %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(avg_banding = mean(Banding), n=n())

   group avg_banding     n
   <int>       <dbl> <int>
 1     1       114       2
 2     2       153       6
 3     3       114       4
 4     4       120       3
 5     5       170      10
 6     6       154       2
 7     7       138       2
 8     8        57.6     2
 9     9       100       2
10    10       119       3
11    11       134       3
12    12       176       6
13    13       127       3
14    14        95.8     2
```

Cost over time:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting. I've had to do this type of analysis about 15 times now. Every time Gender and Country has shown to being important. So I know they need to be included. The primary objective is just to get the values as close to 100 as possible. I've followed your script along.  At the end, the outputs show the number of samples per bin and the average.  Is there a way to figure out what the determinants are (i.e. does 1, 114, 2 refer to male, Canada and alpha?) 

thank you friend.

Comment: You can get that information when you call `summarize`, e.g., `list(Country)` to list out all the countries within a particular group.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 

When I enter the following line per your advice:
dat %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(avg_banding = mean(Banding), n=n(), list(Country))

I end up getting a list where everything is written as <fct [ ]>. perhaps my script is wrong? Thanks again friend!